# command 'll' crashes terminal after rellocating /home

Tags: command-line

I just move my /home and /tmp to another partition and after that I cannot call the commands `ll` or `ls -l` without crashing the console. anything wrong? thank you

Comment: How did you moved `/home` to another partition? What steps did you used?

Comment: Can you use `/bin/ls` alone? Can you run `ls /`? Does this depend on which directory you run `ls` in? Did you move `/home` or your home directory? Please give us some more information.

Comment: are those aliases perhaps?

Comment: Hi. Thansk you all for the help but I figured it out.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I followed this:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Answer (score 4):

after a lot of investigation I found out my /tmp folder had the wrong permissions. All I had to do was setting

```
sudo chmod -R 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: Wow, I accidentally did the same thing and this saved my life!