# Terminal crashes when running lsblk -h

Tags: command-line

Im currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. In the desktop I open a terminal window and type:

```
lsblk -h
```

And the terminal crashes! `lsblk` on its own runs fine. `lsblk --help` also crashes the terminal. If I try the command when SSH into the computer it runs fine. Does any one know how to resolve this problem?

`env` also crashes the terminal. However, if I use SSH the `env` output is:

```
user1@user1:~$ env
XDG_SESSION_ID=4
TERM=vt220
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=023a11a7ff65de4d4b3e1ed65489b4ff-1424963871.263960-1910753503
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/16
USER=user1
LS_COLORS=
MAIL=/var/mail/user1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
PWD=/home/user1
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/user1
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
PYTHONPATH=/home/user1/
LOGNAME=user1
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: What about `lsblk --help`?

Comment: lsblk --help also crashes the terminal

Comment: Does the same happen with other terminals, e. g. `terminator`? What does your shell environment look like (check with `env`)?

Comment: env also crashes the terminal. But iv used ssh to get the setup env output

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crashes the terminal"? Is there an error message, maybe in a logfile?

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/525671/command-ll-crashes-terminal-after-rellocating-home